# Bootstrap buttons not sitting apart

Tags: css, angular, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

On the [getbootstrap doc page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#examples) for buttons the example buttons have a `type` and two css classes:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

The buttons sit very neatly, slightly apart.

[image]

I have a simple Angular 12 application into which I have installed bootstrap 3, like so:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@3
```

In my application the buttons site completely flush with each other, using this code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Server</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Blueprint</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And look like this:

[image]

I am certain the bootstrap css is included, because if I remove the `"node_modules/boo..."` line from the `angular.json` file:

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

All the styling from the page completely disappears.

So, if I am correctly loading the bootstrap styling and applying it to the buttons, why do they not present as neatly as the example buttons in the docs?

Comment: Try removing `src/styles.css` instead see if it fixes the buttons gap

Comment: @MattW check if the parent div of buttons is getting `display: flex` from somewhere, if its a big problem plz replicate in a stackblitz and share back, currently nothing can be done in terms of debugging!

Comment: the btn class of bootstrap has **no** margin, you can add using `mx-1`, see [spacing utilies](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/): the "m" is about margin, the "x" about left and right, the "1" a .25rem, e.g. `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-1">Primary</button>`.  You see spacing in the page you indicate because a css of the page.NOTE: If you use another version of bootstrap.css see that the utilities has change (in bootstrap 4 you use "ml-1 mr-2", I can not remember if in bootstrap 3 do you have this utilities)